# How can i keep an editText with mouse cursor in destiny position of Android animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext

I have an EditText that, in the Focus event, translate to top of screen, but, the mouse cursor keep in initial position. What i need to do to my mouse cursor go with the animation and stay static in the destiny position so that the typed text show only at the final position of animation?

I try this way, but no have success:

```
public void moveEditTextSearch() {
    Animation moveEdit = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-700);
    moveEdit.setDuration(1000);
    moveEdit.setFillAfter(true);
    pesquisa.startAnimation(moveEdit);
}
```